# Migrating from MSSQL to MYSQL error 1064 MYSQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql-server, mysql-workbench, database-migration

I am currently preparing a migration from MSSQL to MYSQL using MYSQL workbench.

The error I am receiving is as follows.

```
ERROR: Error executing 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dbo`.`VendorGTG` (
  `VID` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `Attending` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT '',
  `Name1` VARCHAR(50) NULL COMMENT '',
  `Name2` VARCHAR(50) NULL COMMENT '',
  `Inserted` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT '',
  `NameTag` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`VID`)  COMMENT '')'
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'COMMENT '')' at line 8.
SQL Error: 1064
```

Comment: @TTeeple Please read questions carefully before suggesting edits like that. This question DOES relate to SQL Server.

Comment: @DavidG I would argue that. OP is migrating from SQL Server but the error in question is MySQL related.

Comment: @TTeeple And yet the code posted is SQL Server syntax. Either way, it doesn't warrant an edit suggestion to remove the tag.

Comment: @DavidG `COMMENT, TINYINT(1)`, encasing all the columns in quotes, that all screams MySQL syntax to me.

Comment: @TTeeple Because it's only partially converted from SQL Server syntax. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't have schemas like SQL Server, so remove that from your code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS VendorGTG (
  `VID` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `Attending` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT '',
  `Name1` VARCHAR(50) NULL COMMENT '',
  `Name2` VARCHAR(50) NULL COMMENT '',
  `Inserted` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT '',
  `NameTag` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`VID`)  COMMENT '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with `COMMENT ''` - just remove all occurence of that. Feel free to leave a comment under this bug http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=77910
We're working on it to fix it.